# Single-post preview repeats thumbnails in Jupiter Recent Posts widget

Tags: thumbnails, post-meta, recent-posts

I'm using the Jupiter theme version 5.1.8 with WordPress version 4.6.

When I preview a single post, the thumbnails displayed by the Jupiter theme's Recent Posts widget are all repeats of the current page's thumbnail. They are not displaying the thumbnails of the recent posts, as they should.  I have noticed that the edit-post preview button results in a redirect URL with a `_thumbnail_id` parameter.  If I remove that parameter, then the proper thumbnails are displayed. Also, when I view the post with the permalink URL, then it looks OK. The Jupiter support person says that this is a bug in WordPress. Their quotes below:

> It appears to be a bug in WordPress itself, the get_post_meta() function in particular returns the same _thumbnail_id when used in the conditions you specified in your ticket.
>
> This problem occurs in the Twenty Sixteen 1.6 theme ( with the plugins Recent Posts Widget Extended and Recent Posts Widget With Thumbnails  installed ) when previewing posts with the _thumbnail_id parameter set.

Has anyone else noticed this problem?

Comment: This problem has gone away for me.

Answer (score 0):

i'm experiencing same problem without Jupiter theme. Few plugins and theme i developed uses wp_query for secondary loops like related posts and archive for same category. Whenever I edit single post and click preview changes i get same thumbnail all over web.

Figured out which filter does this. Just set it like this and you will see correct thumbs:

```
add_filter('get_post_metadata','__return_null',11);
```

But the main thumb/featured image will be last saved, may be different you actually selected when clicking preview.

**AND BE CAREFUL THIS COULD CAUSE OTHER PROBLEMS WITH POST METADATA AS WELL.**

Better way should be removing this filter like this:

```
remove_filter('get_post_metadata','_wp_preview_post_thumbnail_filter');
```

but this didn't work in my case.